# NaN error when trying to add variables

Tags: javascript, html, input, calculator, nan

when i run this with the rest of my code everything works fine except this! i just get something saying £NaN0 i dont understand why it is not a number someone please help!

Comment: NaN is not a number, and occurs when you try to do mathy things with something that cannot be converted to a number. What inputs are you using?

Comment: the inputs im using is in the top bit of code ive shown(my html code)

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you posted is fine, but the code you haven't posted is not.

I ran your code with the blueprint/VPS stuff commented out, and it worked just fine. I'm guessing your problem is here:

```
var userChoiceBlueprntVal = blueprtSelected.options[blueprtSelected.selectedIndex].value;
var userChoiceBlueprntValint = parseInt(userChoiceBlueprntVal);
```

What are you getting for `userChoiceBlueprntVal`? More than likely it is not an int, which makes `userChoiceBlueprntValint` NaN, and subsequently all the rest of your calculations.

If you can't fix it from here, post all of your code.

Comment: @user3476638 `<option>Select from:</option>` will give NaN if that is selected. Either give it a default value or do some error checking. Also, you're still missing code. Try creating a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ put your code/html in that, save it, then paste the link for us to run it

Comment: okay thanks adding the value to  the <option>Select from:</option> worked!

Comment: @user3476638 No problem, be sure to select this as the accepted answer if everything is working